# How to make BufferedImage from OutputStream

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I started to use LLJTran to make lossless rotation of JPEG image.
The only problem I have with this library is its iterface.

Ideally the transform() would return BufferedImage object but instead it does not return anything and just writes the the OutputStream.

Here is the API.
http://mediachest.sourceforge.net/mediautil/javadocs/mediautil/image/jpeg/LLJTran.html

Does anyone know how I can get BufferedImage from the OutputStream?

Comment: Why don't you rotate yourself if all you want is a `BufferedImage`? Note that `BufferedImage` contains uncompressed data and thus would support lossless rotation. It seems like LLJTran would return the recompressed JPEG data in the `OutputStream` and thus you'd have to decompress again in order to get a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: I am not sure about that but when I save the OutputStream to a file I get the perfectly rotated image, I don't think it's compressed at all. I just don't want to do the save to file and then read back from file. I want to use streams just don't know how. I'm fairly new to Streams in Java

Comment: If you just write the OutputStream to the file and you get a perfect JPEG file without doing more, it sure contains compressed data. As I said, read the JPEG into an uncompressed BufferedImage and rotate yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know how I can get BufferedImage from the OutputStream?

1. Create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`
2. Read bytes from the OS, write to BAOS.
3. When done, the BAOS will contain all the bytes.  Use `BAOS.toByteArray()` to get the `byte[]`.
4. Hand the `byte[]` returned as an argument to the constructor of a  `ByteArrayInputStream`.
5. Pass the BAIS to `ImageIO.read(InputStream)`.

Comment: I'll try it. Do you know if I can use ImageOutputStream instead? I mean, is there a way to use ImageOutputStream as an object of the OutputStream to output will be written into the ImageOutputStream?

Comment: I don't know, but what is the advantage?

Answer (score 1):

```
OutputStream os = new FileStream(​strFilePath, FileMode.Create);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(is);
```

Literally just 3 lines of code. Don't know why we try to make things difficult for each other.

Comment: OutputStream' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Answer (score 0):

use `ImageIO.read(InputStream input)`

Comment: I don't understand it. Where do I get the InputStream? Can you write a complete code? I need to create some type out OutputStream object that would have underlying INputStream object in it. Is that right? How do I do this?

Comment: AlexR, that means writing to a file and then reading from it, two steps what could be not so efficient as writing to a "pipe" and building the BufferedImage from it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try and do the rotation yourself, since `BufferedImage` would contain uncompressed data anyways.
Thus decompress the JPEG file into a `BufferedImage`, which then should allow lossless rotation (due to the uncompressed data).

Example:

```
File unrotatedImageFile = ...;
BufferedImage srcImage = ImageIO.read( unrotatedImageFile );

AffineTransformOp t = new AffineTransformOp( 
    AffineTransform.getRotateInstance( Math.toRadians( 90.0 ) ), 
    AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR );
BufferedImage rotatedImage = t.filter( srcImage, null );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `BasicJpeg`, a subclass of `LLJTran`?
It has a `getBufferedImage()` method, but the documentation is not that verbose... and I don't know the API.

If this does not work, you can let `LLJTran` write to a `PipedOutputStream` connected to a `PipedInputStream` that will feed the `ImageIO` as suggested by AlexR.

Comment: Tried it. Does not work. getBufferedImage() gives errors, something to do with im == null. Other than that I like the LLJTran library, it's the only one that rotates my large jpeg 90 degrees without any problems